# Error compiling in release mode or ad-hoc mode, Xamarin Forms iOS,

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have an error in xamarin forms ios, and it only happens in release mode, or Ad-Hoc mode, in debug mode if the app works, why is it?

> Error     Failed to resolve "System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod"
>   reference from "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"  TuFacturadorApp.iOS         Compilación

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to determine what code/package is pulling that code in as you can not use `Reflection.Emit` in a release configuration iOS build.

Note: Also make sure that your linker setting for your Release configuration is **not** set to "Don't link"

> No Dynamic Code Generation
>
> Since the iPhone's kernel prevents an application from generating code dynamically Mono on the iPhone does not support any form of dynamic code generation. These include:
>
> - The System.Reflection.Emit is not available.
> - No support for System.Runtime.Remoting.
> - No support for creating types dynamically (no Type.GetType ("MyType`1")), although looking up existing types (Type.GetType ("System.String") for example, works just fine).
>   Reverse callbacks must be registered with the runtime at compile time.

re: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/limitations/#No_Dynamic_Code_Generation

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @SushiHangover, but the only library that could be calling Reflection.Emit, would be NewtonSoft.Json, is there a library for Xamarin Forms, which can replace NewtonSoft.Json?

Comment: @OscarNavarro NewtonSoft should be fine, it does use reflection to lookup classes, .ctors, props, ... but does not create code on the fly via emit. What version of Xamarin.iOS are you running? And what is the linker set to?